# Python not returning the same object?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    nodes = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []

        Node.nodes[self.name] = self

    def addParent(self, parent):
        print "adding parent %s for %s " % (parent, self.name)
        self.parent.append(parent)
        print self.parent

    def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def removeParent(self, parent):
        try:
            self.parent.remove(parent)
        except:
            pass

    def removeChild(self, child):
        try:
            self.children.remove(child)
        except:
            pass

def lookup(obj):
    print "calling look up"
    Node.nodes.get(obj)

def create_node(obj):
    return lookup(obj) or Node(obj)

# Tree has Nodes
class Tree:
    trees = {}

    def __init__(self, name, root):
        self.name = name
        self.root = root
        self.size = 1
        self.nodes = set() # tree has unique nodes

        self.nodes.add(root)
        Tree.trees[self.name] = self

    def addNode(self, node):
        self.nodes.add(node)
        self.size += 1

    def removeNode(self, node):
        try:
            self.nodes.remove(node)
        except:
            return
        self.size -= 1

    def setRoot(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def print_tree(self):
        for i in self.nodes:
            if i == self.root.name:
                print "root: %s" % i
            else:
                print i

def main():
    roota = create_node("a")
    ta = Tree("a", roota)

    childaa = create_node("a_a")
    roota.addChild(childaa)
    childaa.addParent(roota)
    ta.addNode(childaa)

    childab = create_node("a_b")
    roota.addChild(childab)
    childab.addParent(roota)
    ta.addNode(childab)


    # make one of the child of a root
    rootb = create_node("a_a")  # should give me a node that already exists from the above tree
    tb = Tree("a_a", rootb)

    childbb = create_node("a_b") # this node should have two parents now, a and a_a
    rootb.addChild(childbb)
    childbb.addParent(rootb)
    tb.addNode(childbb)

    for node in Node.nodes.itervalues():
        print "Name: %s" % node.name
        if node.parent:
            print "Parent: %s" % [parent.name for parent in node.parent]
        else:
            print "Parent: %s" % node.parent
        print "Children: ", [node.name for node in node.children]
        print ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the output of the script:

```
Name: a  
Parent: []  
Children:  ['a_a', 'a_b']  

Name: a_a  
Parent: []  
Children:  ['a_b']  

Name: a_b  
Parent: ['a_a']  
Children:  []
```

`a_a` should have parent `a`.               line 80 is adding `a` as a parent for `a_a`
`a_b` should have parent `a_a` and `a`.       line 85 is adding `a` as a parent for `a_b`

can someone explain to me why that's not the case in this code?

And desired the output of the script:

```
Name: a  
Parent: []  
Children:  ['a_a', 'a_b']  

Name: a_a  
Parent: ['a']  
Children:  ['a_b']  

Name: a_b  
Parent: ['a', 'a_a']  
Children:  []
```

Comment: Please do not use `except: pass` *ever*. It really swallows everything including SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt. If you really want to ignore all actual *exceptions*, use `except Exception: pass`. But even that is a bad idea - `ValueError` is all you need to catch anyway

Comment: What steps have you taken in trying to figure out the bug? We could hunt through the code and find the bug, but it'd better if you learned how to find it yourself.

Comment: @WinstonEwert just printing at each step of adding child/parent. i saw the the len of Node obj is three so it seems to be performing lookup so then when a_a is lookedup, it should give me a node that already has 'a' as a parent but it doesnt so i am here asking.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the second call to create_node("a_a") gives you back the same node as the first time?

Comment: @WinstonEwert yes and it gives me a_a that doesnt have "a" as a parent.

Comment: `str.format` is preferred over the older `%` style string formatting, for example `"adding parent {} for {} ".format(parent, self.name)`.  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: This indicates one of two things: the parent got removed, or you got back a different object the second time. Can you tell which happened?

Comment: @WinstonEwert my guess is that i am getting a different obj. thats why my question title is "not returning the same object" but i am not sure why it is not returning the same object

Comment: You can check if its the same object by using `print rootb is childaa`. If it prints False, they are different objects. In your case, it does print False. In order to figure out why, I'd add print statements inside `create_node` to see what's happening in there differently than you expect.

Comment: @WinstonEwert it says False so somehow i need to make it return the same object.

Comment: add print statements inside create_node, for the result of the two functions you call. One of them isn't doing what you think.

Comment: @WinstonEwert this is interesting. when i do print Node.nodes.get('a_a').name, it works but when i do lookup('a_a').name, then it failes but lookup does Node.nodes.get()... so it should be the same thing.. Does something happen when it's being pushed as an argument?

Comment: Look very carefully at lookup. You've got something very important missing from the last line.

Comment: @WinstonEwert oh wow. how did i miss that!!! thank you! it works now

Comment: one more tip, you might want to have `lookup` be a [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) of Node , rather than a free function

Comment: @RyanHaining okay i will look into that (never used classmethod before). thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A tree is a directed cyclic-free graph. Each node of a tree is itself a tree, hence you don't need two classes for tree and node (except you want to give some metainfo to your tree).

It is sufficient to keep track either of children or of the parent, but for convenience sake (e.g. transversing the tree in both directions) you can save both. But if you do, you have to take care that isParent(a,b) be tautological to isChild(b,a). In your code, if you add a node and don't manually set its parent, your tree goes haywire.

Said this, "# this node should have two parents now, a and a_a" doesn't make much sense if we are talking about trees.

A basic tree structure looks like this (not validating for cycles):

```
class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, payload):
        self.payload = payload
        self.children = set ()
        self.parent = None

    def __iadd__ (self, child):
        if child.parent: raise Exception ('Node already attached')
        child.parent = self #update parent
        self.children.add (child) #update children's list
        return self

    def detach (self):
        if not self.parent: return
        self.parent.children.remove (self) #update parent's children's list
        self.parent = None #update self

    def pprint (self, level = 0):
        print (' ' * level + self.payload)
        for child in self.children:
            child.pprint (level + 2)
```

And an example is this:

```
root = Tree ('root')
a = Tree ('A')
b = Tree ('B')
c = Tree ('C')
root += a
root += b
b += c

root.pprint ()
c.detach ()
a += c
root.pprint ()
```

I hope you can take some ideas from this snippet about how to build a tree.